# Variable value(hash) in Java While debugging

Tags: java, debugging, hash

I experienced a scenario where I find null pointer exception every time, I printed all the arguments when I'm passing them to that particular function and it is printing on console. While debugging I found a value for each variable but I found a column called "hash" which is '0'. Could anyone explain what is that? Does it relate to the exception(Null pointer) which I'm experiencing now? You can see column 'sValue' which is shown in the picture is the point where I'm getting an exception. 
[image]

Comment: No that has nothing to do with NPE.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every object in JAVA has hash code associated to it generated by hashCode()(public int hashCode()). This hash is representing that value.